# How to use localStorage in server components in NextJS 13 app directory?

Tags: reactjs, next.js, zustand, react-server-components

So I am calling an API inside `Metadata` to fetch details on the URL entered. To access the URL, I am using `next/headers`.

```
export async function generateMetadata(
  { params, searchParams }: MetadataProps,
  parent: ResolvingMetadata
): Promise<Metadata> {
  // read route params
  const id = params.id;

  const headersList = headers();
  const domain = headersList.get("x-forwarded-host") || "localhost:3000"; // get url
  

  // fetch data
  const hotelAuth = await fetch(
    `apidomain.com/parameter/[url-of-the-website]`,
    { next: { revalidate: 3600 } }
  ).then((res) => res.json());

  return {
    title: hotelAuth?.data?.hotel_name,
    description: hotelAuth?.data?.hotel_description,
    openGraph: {
      title: hotelAuth?.data?.hotel_name,
      description: hotelAuth?.data?.hotel_description,
    },
  };
}
```

I want to access the `domain` variable in other component or possibly store the `hotelAuth` response in zustand.

I tried creating a custom hook for making the api call second time but I still need to access the URL.

```
"use client";
import { useEffect } from 'react';
import useSWR from "swr";
import apiEndpoints from "./endpoints";
import getResponse from "./getResponse";

export const useHotelAuth = () => {
    const { auth } = apiEndpoints.GET;

    useEffect(()=>{
        if (typeof window !== 'undefined'){
            console.log(window.location.href)
        }
    }, [window])

    const { data, isLoading, error } = useSWR(`apiEnpoint/[url-of-the-current-site]`, getResponse);

    return { hotelAuthData: data, hotelAuthLoading: isLoading, error };
};
```

and this gives error as: `window is not defined`

So how can I get the URL in the client side and how can I pass data from the server side component to client side or store in zustand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem appears to revolve around how you incorporate the `window` parameter within the `useEffect` dependency array.

```js
  useEffect(() => {
    if (typeof window !== "undefined") {
      console.log(window.location.href);
    }
  }, []); //remove window parameter
```